# React Native Android libc.so crash on first open after installation

Tags: android, react-native

Everything is working fine in debug mode. If I uninstall the app and reinstall from an apk, the first time is crashing. When I reopen, starts working fine.

- React Native: 0.67.4
- React: 18.0.0
- Android compileSdkVersion 32
- ndkVersion 21.4.7075529

build.gradle includes maven `maven {url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")}` and installed jsc-android version is 250230.2.1 (it's added automatically)

````
2022-05-02 17:34:43.291 31541-31541/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x48 in tid 31541 (dev.wilav), pid 31541 (dev.wilav)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/r0qxxx/r0q:12/SP1A.210812.016/S901EXXU1AVCJ:user/release-keys'
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '13'
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: Processor: '6'
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2022-05-02 17:34:43.403049627-0300
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: Process uptime: 8s
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: Cmdline: dev.wilav
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: pid: 31541, tid: 31541, name: dev.wilav  >>> dev.wilav <<<
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10750
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x48
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     x0  000000000000000a  x1  0000007fd7fe2330  x2  0000007fd7fe23b0  x3  0000000000001286
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000008  x6  000000006f3cd410  x7  000000006ff836d8
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     x8  00000076f11cac10  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000007823d06000  x11 00000000000000e0
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000017  x13 0000000019f645d0  x14 000000000ba350b0  x15 00000babf1e10eee
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007a7f1a4d50  x17 0000007a8a54ee24  x18 0000007a9ee0c000  x19 b400007833d02d10
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000000000001286  x22 0000000000001286  x23 b400007833d02d10
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     x24 000000007fffffff  x25 0000007a9e20e000  x26 0000000015180000  x27 b4000077c3d7b120
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     x28 000000006f476c68  x29 0000007fd7fe3580
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:     lr  0000007a9f3b689c  sp  0000007fd7fe2310  pc  00000076f0f9f3bc  pst 0000000060001000
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 00000000006703bc  /data/app/~~W6WxLFf0lAgav9RnC1zd9w==/dev.wilav-MbM1NCrTCJZCjYopf93dSQ==/lib/arm64/libjsc.so (BuildId: dad225e5c5aafb43e3fcbfcd576772a6a0f8c19a)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 000000000000089c  [vdso]
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 00000000000a30b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8) (BuildId: ea614e5d67d01effce7dc685388edeee)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 0000000000017ea8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+184) (BuildId: 748948a5650ad93d18b12eb1d9a51a89)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 0000000000017d84  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+116) (BuildId: 748948a5650ad93d18b12eb1d9a51a89)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 000000000015917c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, int)+48) (BuildId: 84bf0c41679a7cdc7963b099e071b348)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 000000000028544c  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+108)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 00000000007ecd28  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.MessageQueue.next+232)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 00000000007e9f14  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loopOnce+100)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 00000000007e9e14  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+516)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 0000000000565d70  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+800)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 00000000002ca9e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 000000000035b5d0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (_jobject* art::InvokeMethod<(art::PointerSize)8>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+608) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 000000000035b348  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+52) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 00000000000b2f74  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+132) (BuildId: ad9ee401645a5135206a62ff86fc2ef5cdc29120)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 0000000000b3e04c  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+140)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 0000000000b474a8  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+2376)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 00000000002ca9e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 000000000044ca04  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+464) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 000000000062cf30  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+268) (BuildId: 34e3dd028e2e682b63a512d6a4f1b5eb)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 00000000000b3bf8  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+124) (BuildId: 84bf0c41679a7cdc7963b099e071b348)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 00000000000c01e4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+852) (BuildId: 84bf0c41679a7cdc7963b099e071b348)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #22 pc 00000000000025d0  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1400) (BuildId: bce2def038894c7d698a2968af787809)
2022-05-02 17:34:43.903 32397-32397/? A/DEBUG:       #23 pc 000000000004a068  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+100) (BuildId: ea614e5d67d01effce7dc685388edeee)```
````

Comment: did you fix the issue? I'm experiencing the same but don't know how to fix

Answer (score 1):

It's still an open issue on RN repo since February 2022, you can find more details [there](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33083).